# Use the css selector in @Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: razor, css-selectors

Can I use CSS Selector in @Html.TextBox?
For example, how can I write input below?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="Event_EndDateTime" name="Event_EndDateTime" data-datetimepicker="true" data-datetimepicker-counter="1" lang="en" value="@Model.Event_EndDateTime"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to use the html helpers to get your desired result:

```
@Html.TextBox("Event_EndDateTime", Model.Event_EndDateTime, new { @class = "form-control text-center", data_datetimepicker = "true" data_datetimepicker_counter = 1, lang = "en" })
```

or using `@Html.TextBoxFor` :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Event_EndDateTime, new { @class = "form-control text-center", data_datetimepicker = "true" data_datetimepicker_counter = 1, lang = "en" })
```